# iOS IAP: How to veriy that user was really charged for transaction

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, skpaymenttransaction

I am using

```
paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])
```

and inside I am of course handling the `transactionState`. Everything is working fine, but now I want to add proper tracking.

There is the special case, when a user bought the `SKPRoduct` already before but hits the buy again (i.e. after a fresh install) Then he wont be charged again, but the transaction state will be `.purchased` even though it was a restore.

Is this only happening in the sandbox environment? I did not yet publish it so I don't have any live experience about this, but I wonder if there is a correct way to find out if the transaction was really a purchase, or in fact a restore?

Answer (score 0):

First of all when user installs the app and clicks buy you dim the display and wait until delegate methods inform you that payment occurred successfully then you store a boolean in user defaults that user bought the IAP , whenever you open the VC with buy button check the boolean and hide/show it accordingly

**Note:** re-charge won't happen again if user deletes the app after purchase and installs it again and clicks buy

Comment: well, but what about a re-installment? everything is working fine, i am just wondering how to distinguish a new purchase from a restore-purchase transation

Comment: If you have a login system make a boolean upthere in server if not , users already know that and Apple will reject your buy VC if it hasn't a restore button

Comment: there is no user management or other server involved, so i cannot persist this information anywhere

Comment: actually re-charge won't happen again anyway even if user clicks buy button delegate will run only , as Apple servers already keeps these data

Comment: i know. maybe i was not clear. everything works fine. the only thing i want to find out, is "did the transaction with the state '.purchased' charge the user or not"

Comment: You mean if user buy the IAP then deletes it and reinstalls it a gain and click bug , answer is re-charge won't happen again , to be sure try a payment of your own app from an account and do it again charge is only once for a Consumable IAP

Comment: yes.. thats the scenario what i mean. the user is not charged, but the transaction within `paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])` will have the state `.purchased` and not `.restored`